# Where is this function continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

To be continuous on an interval a function has to have a value for every point on that interval. So I think this function is continuous everywhere it is defined all unioned together. I get

```
[-6,-5)U(-5,-3)U(-3,-2]U(-2,1)U(1,3)U(3,5]U(5,7]
```

But my professor says it's

```
(-5-3)U(-2,1)U(1,3)
```

Which doesn't make sense to me at all.

- Why not [-6, -5)?
- Why not [-3, -2)?
- Why not [3, 5]!!!?
- Why not (5, 7]?

[image]

Comment: What is the function? If just as drawn, then both of your answers are incorrect.

Comment: Everywhere but places where you have to lift your pen (basically). BUt I can't even see the details of the picture.

Comment: Are you sure the professor was referring to the same problem?

Comment: Yeah, it;s definitely the same problem. I'm hoping my answer is just incorrect cause I used brackets. It's possible he was just trying to point out something I missed and not provide the whole answer. idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is NOT continuous at any of the closed endpoints. Continuity must apply from both directions, not just one. That's why only the open intervals with open images are continuous. So Deusovi's comment is correct: all the *open* intervals are valid continuous segments for the function. Deusovi should make that an answer.

Comment: The professor's answer is missing some intervals entirely - the correct answer is the OP's, with all brackets changed to parentheses.

Comment: So you never use brackets because it has to be continuous from the left and right, and if we used brackets we would only have it at the point and from one side but not the point and both sides?

Comment: @Deusovi is correct, see my edited answer. And yes, your comment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

QUOTE "To be continuous on an interval a function has to have a value for every point on that interval." END QUOTE

That is nowhere near the truth.  Take the function that is equal to $0$ on the interval $[0,1/2)$ and equal to $1$ on the interval $[1/2,\ 1]$.  That has a value everywhere in the interval $[0,1]$, but it has a discontinuity at $1/2$.